# Comparing between two dates in Oracle DB is not giving proper result

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I've got two `DATE` columns in my table having below values:

```
Order_date  Service_date
01-06-17    31-01-18
01-06-17    01-10-18
01-06-17    01-07-18
01-06-17    01-04-18`
```

When I run the below query:

```
SELECT
    TRUNC(Order_date) Order_date,
    TRUNC(Service_date) Service_date,
    CASE
        WHEN trunc(Order_date) > trunc(Service_date) THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END actual
FROM
    table_x;
```

I get the result as:

```
Order_date  Service_date  actual
01-06-17    31-01-18      Y
```

The expected answer should be 'N'.

But if I run a similar query, by actually passing the `DATE` values, it gives me proper result.

```
SELECT
    to_date('01-06-17','DD-MM-RR') Order_date,
    to_date('31-01-18', 'DD-MM-RR') Service_date,
    CASE
        WHEN to_date('01-06-17','DD-MM-RR') > to_date('31-01-18', 'DD-MM-RR') THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END actual
FROM
    table_x;

Order_date  Service_date  actual
01-06-17    31-01-18      N
```

Why isn't it giving the the expected result with the original query?

Comment: Are you sure all the stored dates are in the century you expect? Try querying your table with the full-year format model (`to_char(order_date, 'SYYYY-MM-DD')` and `to_char(service_date, 'SYYYY-MM-DD')` and see what those show.

Comment: ohh yes .. u r right .. how silly of me to not check the entire year .. in DB, service_date is actually 31-01-0118

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for ur help

Comment: That's why you should configure your SQL tool to always show the full year.